# Outlook 2007 - Move to Folder Function

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007

Until recently, when I opened the Move To Folder function in Outlook 2007, the last accessed file folder would be highlighted. That made it easy to move another file there which happens often whenever a back and forth thread is going on.

Last week, all of a sudden, when I open Move To Folder, it highlights one particular folder, one I almost never use. Even if I had just moved a folder into a different folder, it comes up on the same obscure one.

I’ve tried ever thing I know to reset it  to the previous default with no luck.

Comment: can you clarify your question?

Comment: When I want to move an email from my inbox to a folder that's relevant to that email, I right click the email and then hit the Move to folder tab. When I do that the list of folders used to comes up on the last folder I accessed. Now it comes up on one particular folder every time - not the last one I accessed.

Answer (score 0):

You can try clearing the Most Recently Used (MRU) list for "Move to Folder history".

http://www.slipstick.com/outlook/clearing-outlooks-most-recently-used-mru-lists/

"If you want to clear the list, you need to delete the appropriate registry value. Because the values are stored in binary format, you can’t edit the list to remove some entries from it, only delete the entire list. The next time Outlook is used, **it will recreate a blank key**."

"In Outlook 2010 and older, navigate to the profile key, found at:
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows Messaging Subsystem\Profiles\profile\0a0d020000000000c000000000000046"

Move to Folder history is 101f031e

More at http://www.howto-outlook.com/howto/clearmru.htm